# Check if needed files are in filepaths

Tags: python, path

I am working on a workaround for my cloud-app, that downloads the needed files, if git lfs is not supported.

However, I need to check for `wandering-sponge-4.pth`, `label_embeddings.npy` in the root folder and `pytorch_model.bin` under `distilbert-dlf/pytorch_model.bin`

I used `Path` to check all directories and save them as a string inside an array, so I can check for the above files afterwards.

I came up with the code down below, that returns me true, if all files are available.

***It always prints false, although every file is in place. What did I miss?***

(I need to check the described three names in my array of strings)

```
 # ugly workaround because streamlit cloud doesn't support git lfs -.-
for model in Path().cwd().glob("./*"):
    foundFiles.append(str(model))
for files in Path().cwd().glob("distilbert-dlf/*"):
    foundFiles.append(str(files))

checkFiles = ["pytorch_model.bin", "wandering-sponge-4.pth", "label_embeddings.npy"]

output = any([substring in checkFiles for substring in foundFiles])
print(output, foundFiles)
```

Output:

> False
> ['/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/labels.csv', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/temp', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/.DS_Store', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/requirements.txt', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/tempDir', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/**pycache**', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/env', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/.gitignore', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/wandering-sponge-4.pth', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/helper.py', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/.gitattributes', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/app.py', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/packages.txt', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/.git', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/label_embeddings.npy', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/distilbert-dlf', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/distilbert-dlf/config.json', '/Users/lafllamme/Projects/transcript-app/distilbert-dlf/pytorch_model.bin']

I want to achieve something like this:

```
if (file1, file2 not in directory and file 3 not in subdirectory):
   ....
```

**Solution:**

```
for model in Path().cwd().glob("./*"):
    foundFiles.append(str(model))
for files in Path().cwd().glob("distilbert-dlf/*"):
    foundFiles.append(str(files))

checkFiles = ("distilbert-dlf/pytorch_model.bin", "wandering-sponge-4.pth", "label_embeddings.npy")
for path in checkFiles:
    if os.path.exists(path)==True:
        print('I found:', path)
```

Comment: None of the strings in `foundFiles` is contained in `checkFiles`, it's that simple.

Comment: Can you write a normal `for` loop (or, as a hint: two `for` loops) to achieve what you want?

Comment: check my edited post

Comment: Are you sure it returns true only if all the files in your check list are here ? If there are only two of them, ```any([True, False, False, ..., True]) ==  True``` => It's ```True``` if at least one of the files is here. And for your issue ... That's normal i guess, you should do the opposite way maybe ? Looking if the ```checkfiles``` are in the ```foundfiles```, otherwise, you look for the whole path to be in the ```checkfiles```

Comment: Didn't work, found another solution!

Comment: FWIW, Streamlit Cloud does support Git LFS per the comment in the original snippet

Comment: what do you mean???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the other way, looking if the check files are in the found files. Otherwise, you look for the whole path:

Basically, inverting your last condition should be enough:

```
output = any([[checkFile in substring for substring in foundFiles] for checkFile in checkFiles])
```

This will be true if there is AT LEAST one of the files. To know if they are all here:

```
output = all([any([checkFile in substring for substring in foundFiles]) for checkFile in checkFiles])
```